# mceRepaint of tinymce not works in ie7?

Tags: jquery, tinymce, internet-explorer-7

Once i edited image inside tinymce. i had used `tinyMCE.execCommand("mceRepaint");` to repaint and remove image selection.

`tinyMCE.execCommand("mceRepaint");` works in all browser but ie7 selector is still display after editing image. **How can i remove selector of image inside tinymce while using ie7**

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collapse the selection to remove the drag handles in IE:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.collapse()
```

This will also keep the cursor position relatively close to where the user expects it to be.  Alternatively, the cleanup command will remove the handles in all browsers (along with the selection):

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceCleanup');
```